# How do you change the order of an object in a cell?

Tags: r, dataframe

I might be overcomplicating this but is it possible to reverse the order of an object? For example, if I have observation "66-022", could I change it to "022-66"?

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(x, "-"), \(x) paste(rev(x), collapse = "-"))`?

Comment: The literal (and perhaps naive/short-sighted) solution might be as simple as `sub("(.*)-(.*)", "\\2-\\1", "66-022")` (replacing the literal `"66-022"` with a vector of strings, if needed). But it's not clear if that is the only consideration for your needs. If that doesn't work, you should [edit] your question and add more context, including sample data, code attempted, and expected output. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for demonstrations of how to use `dput(x)` to share unambiguous data. Thanks!

Comment: Love these suggestions! So for added context these are precincts that I am matching to specific IDs using VLookup. So an example of one of the observations is: "011-73, 038-73, 039-73, 043-73, 001-76, 002-76, 008-76, 009-76, 010-76 (Combined into 008-76), 011-76, 012-76, 013-76, 014-76, 015-76, 016-76, 017-76, 018-76, 019-76, 020-76, 021-76, 023-76, 024-76, 025-76 (Combined into 023-76), 028-76, 030-76, 037-76, 038-76, 039-76"

Comment: I figured I would just separate them out, flip them, then use vlookup, then put them all back together again with a comma separator. I am concerned about the possible errors that could occur by spreading them out to so many columns but not sure if there's a better alternative here